# React Material-UI: the key provided to the classes property is not implemented in undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to override Material-UI styles using `makeStyles()` as described in [docs](https://material-ui.com/styles/advanced/#makestyles). But I've got a warning when I pass a class name in classes props from parent component which is not described in `useStyles`. Warning says:

> Warning: Material-UI: the key `label` provided to the classes property is not implemented in undefined.
>   You can only override one of the following: root.

Example in [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-loevt)

I know if I uncomment `label: {}` in useStyles this error will disappear. But I'm making a component library, so there may be passed all of the attributes of `Button` component, as it's described [here](https://material-ui.com/api/button/#css).

**So, the questions:**

1. Do I really need to list all of this props of `Button`?
2. How can I prioritize the applying styles (styles inside component's `useStyles` would have lower priority, than class names, passed via props)?

Answer (score 2):

You can just override `makeStyle` classes, `{ ...classes, label: 'my-color2' }`, for [example](https://h75l0.codesandbox.io/):

```js
export default function ContainedButtons(props) {
  const classes = useStyles(props);

  return (
    <div>
      <Button variant="contained" classes={{ ...classes }}>
        Default
      </Button>
      <Button variant="contained" classes={{ ...classes, label: 'my-color2' }}>
        Default
      </Button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit Q-56805325-LabelProp]

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't solve the problem. I still need to list `label` prop at makeStyles (try to remove them in your example and you have warning). But i don't want to do it, otherwise i could list all css props of `Button`  component

Comment: You have to do it, you get a warning because you pass `<Demo classes={{ label: "my-color", root: "my-margin" }} />` and there is not such key when applied to the first button.

Comment: I know it, so there is no other way than to list all the properties?

Comment: You can through `Button` instance, where do you want to list them? in makeStyles?

Comment: If i list them in makeStyles at least as empty objects then the error will not happen. My `makeStyles` will look like: 
`makeStyles({root: {}, label: {}, text:{}, textPrimary: {} .....})`. I think it's a bit redundant

Comment: Well, you must, add a global object with all attributes and just import it and spread it `...buttonProps`.

Comment: Or you can write a function which makes a style upon adding a property